# Socket connection timed out when sending numpy arrays via sockets to another machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sockets

I have a numpy array. In my code, I want to send the numpy ndarray via sockets, and I have implemented that. It is fully functioning when I use it between a client and server sockets which are hosted on my PC, although when trying to send the ndarray as a client to a server on another PC it doesn't work and shows the 'timed out' - socket error.

I think I have done everything correct though.
Here is how I've built my code:

1. Client sends first message to establish connection.
2. Server sends back that it is ready to receive data.
3. Client sends numpy ndarray as bytes and also the message 
   'transmission_over'.
4. Server sends back that is has received the data.

   ```
   # Client side:
   client_socket.send(data_to_send.encode()) -> Some headers.
   received_data = client_socket.recv(1024) -> Receive data from server.
   print('What I received after sending headers (1): ', received_data.decode())
   client_socket.send(data.tobytes()) -> Sending the ndarray as bytes.
   client_socket.send("transmission_over".encode())
   received_data = client_socket.recv(1024) -> Receive data from server.
   print('What I received after sending the data (2): ', received_data.decode())
   print('sent data!')

   # Server side:
   def receive_numpy_array(connection):
       received_bytes = ''.encode()
       while True:
         raw_data = connection.recv(1024)
         if raw_data == 'transmission_over'.encode():
             break
         received_bytes += raw_data
       np_array_from_bytes = np.frombuffer(received_bytes, dtype=np.uint64).reshape((8192,))
       return np_array_from_bytes

   raw_data = connection.recv(1024) -> Receive headers.
   connection.send("HOST >>> YOU: Ready to receive data!".encode()) -> Sending back that server is ready.
   np_array = receive_numpy_array(connection) -> Receiving & constructing ndarray.
   connection.send("HOST >>> YOU: Received your data segment!".encode()) -> Sending back confirmation.
   ```

When trying this code when client is on one PC and the server on another it doesn't work and it shows the error that the socket timed out inside the receive_numpy_array function.

When testing on my own PC and being both: client and server, it works fine and I successfully retrieve the numpy array.

**So why does this code work only when using the same machine for client and server and how to fix that?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using restricted port(or wrong interface, firewall exception). Most error 1-Bind to loopback(bad idea), 2-Wrong port(<1024), 3-Network netmask(32-24-16-8 ??), 4- Default gateway(Prerouting rule ? )

Answer (score 0):

Purting it abstractly, You have to enable the port forwarding in the router and configue the iptables of the system as well accordingly, Can help u in detail, provided the type of both the operating system, the network they are connected to, (if connected to same or different routers/network)

Comment: I am using a LAN network. But even if they are on the same network and connected to the same routers, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even if they are on same network, your router simply does not allow to send packets to whatever pc you want in the network on a defined port, it has to be configured to follow with your code, If you want you can search google, saying Port Forwarding setup in router, to properly forward the incoming packet on a port to another pc

Comment: I have faced the same problem during mu college project

Comment: Would that really still matter if using a private LAN network like hamachi? And then how come that it only times out at the point of receiving the numpy array and not before?

Comment: Dont know about Hamachi, will get back to you after reading abt that